# Facebook API Marketing with UrlFetchApp

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get my campaign's performance into a Google Spreadsheet. I've written this code

```
function myFunction() {

  var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/CAMPAIGNID/insights"
  var params = {
            'access_token':'MYTOKEN',
                 }
      var options = {
        'method' : 'get',
        'payload' : params
      }
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
 Logger.log(response)
}
```

When I run this code it retrieves me this info :

```
{"report_run_id":"234313017579333"}
```

But I'm looking for the insights of a campaign and not a report. Has anyone got an idea of why it retrieves me this ?

ps: When I run this : 
    `https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/CAMPAIGNID/insights`

in Facebook's Graph API it gives me the insights of the campaign. So I don't understand with I get another answer when I try to do it from Google Apps Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you actually made a POST request, and not a GET - because posting to this edge is supposed to trigger creation of a report in the background, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/#Creating:

> When posting to this edge, an AdReportRun will be created.

---

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params, says in the description of the `payload` parameter,

> Certain HTTP methods (for example, GET) do not accept a payload.

So because you supplied a payload, that probably makes it use POST, and ignore that you tried to specify `'method' : 'get'`

Don’t supply a `payload`, append your access token directly to the URL as a query string parameter instead.

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/CAMPAIGNID/insights?access_token=…"
```

(You can probably remove the `options` object completely then, and call `fetch` with just the URL as single parameter, because GET is the default anyway.)

Comment: I was dealing with this for 5 days now... it finally worked ! HUGE THANKS